# How to pass model attributes to coffeescript for select2 templating in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, jquery-select2

I'm trying to implement [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) in a Rails 3.2 app.

Specifically, I want to use templating to display a country select field with country flags + country names.

I have a Country model and User model. My Country model has a `:code` attribute. I'm using a CSS sprite to display flags, based on the `:code` attribute.

```
<img class="flag flag-#{country.code}">
```

In the User form I have

```
<%= f.collection_select :country_id, Country.order(:name), :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
```

and in user.js.coffee.erb I have

```
jQuery ->  
    format = (country) ->
        "<img class='flag flag-#{country.code}' src='#'/>" + country.name       
    $('#prerep_country_id').select2
        placeholder: "Select a country",
        allowClear: true,
        formatResult: format,
        formatSelection: format
```

I'm having trouble tying it all together (probably part of my ongoing learning of how asset pipeline and js.erb works).

Currently the select field is rendered using select2, but contains only a list of countries. No formatting.

How do I pass each country to the `format = (country)` function so that it gets formatted with the flag?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/#documentation):

> formatSelection
>
> Function used to render the current selection.
>
> ```
> formatSelection(object)
> ```

and the `object` parameter is

> The selected result object returned from the `query` function.

And a little further down we see what `query` is all about, in particular:

> Array of result objects. The default renderers expect objects with `id` and `text` keys. The `id` attribute is required, even if custom renderers are used.

And if we look at an example (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/a73gc/), we'll see that your `format` function is being passed a `country` object with `id` and `text` keys. You, on the other hand, are looking at `country.code` but there's nothing there and you produce images like this:

```
<img class='flag flag-' src='#'/>
```

so you don't get any flags.

Try this instead:

```
format = (country) ->
    "<img class='flag flag-#{country.id}' src='#'/>" + country.name
    #--------------------------------^^
```

Presumably you have `height` and `width` in your `img.flag` CSS already so we don't have to worry about how big the flags are.

Also, if you're using HTML5, you can lose the XML-style `/>` self-closing tag thing, just `<img ...>` is fine.

Comment: thanks for a really useful answer. so to clarify, if I need the `:code` attribute, I could do something like `<img class='flag flag-#{Country.find(country.id).code}'? The problem is I'm not even getting blank img tags in my markup, so I may have two issues to deal with. :)

Comment: @AndyHarvey: Is `$('#prerep_country_id').select2` getting called at all? There should be an `id` in the `country` that is passed to `format`, is `format` getting called?

Comment: yes, `$('#prerep_country_id').select2` is being called, but format isn't. What;s the best way to step through this and work out where it's failing?

Comment: @AndyHarvey: Are you absolutely certain that `format` isn't being called? It works fine in http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/a73gc/ so what is different? Have you checked your whitespace?

Comment: Hi mu, checking my debugger I see `Uncaught ReferenceError: format is not defined`. I'm still not really understanding where the variable `country` is coming from, which is passed to `format`. Have a feeling this may be my issue.

Comment: `country` comes from the plugin, you can see what it is in the fiddle. `format` won't be defined outside the `jQuery ->` but it should be fine when `$('#prerep_country_id').select2` sees it. What is my jsfiddle example doing that your code isn't or vice versa?

Comment: your fiddle is rendering `<li><img >country name</li>`. my code is only rendering `<li>country name</li>`. I'm having trouble seeing what's different between the two. Appreciate any more suggestions. Apologies if I'm being slow.

Comment: Is it binding select2 at all?

Comment: yes, its rendering the select2 ui, but no formatted option list.

Comment: You have checked the whitespace in your CoffeeScript, right? You're using the most recent select2 version, right? If that's fine then you'll have to paste your HTML into that fiddle and reproduce your problem; everything should be working so something is going on that you haven't mentioned.

Comment: ok, after looking at this some more, I found two issues. First, I'd made a small syntax error converting from js to coffee. But the main issue is that I'm trying to call database value into my format string. This doesn't appear to be working for some reason.

Comment: So you're saying that that's not your real code in the question? I don't see any "call database value" in that `format`.

Comment: that is the actual code, hence my question about where the `country` variable comes from. My Country model has several attributes: ID, name, alpha2-code, alpha3-code. The collection select behind select2 is using ID and name. But my images need the alpha2 code. Another example, perhaps I have a user select with ID and name, but need to pass an avatar_url to select2. What I need is something like `<img class=#{Country.find(country.id).alpha >', but I shouldn't be making Ruby queries in coffescript. How could I achieve something like this?

Comment: select2 builds the `country` based on the `<option>` elements inside the `<select>`. So structure your `<select>` properly and you won't need to access the database from the client code.

Comment: thanks mu, sorry I'm being slow. How would I create a select field that would provide the 3 attributes I need in the function: ID, Name and alpha-code?

Comment: You should be able to have `<option value="id">name</option>` to get the `id` and `name` in `country`, then you'd probably need a separate `id`&rarr;`code` map in a (Coffee|Java)Script object, then you should be able to put the pieces together in your formatting function.

Comment: I had added a options_for_collection_select helper method to define a data-code attribute on the select options. But I'm unsure how to access this from the function. `country.data-code` does not work. Is this the wrong approach? I'll give your suggestion a shot. Sorry, my javascript skills are not that great.

Comment: Something like `$('option[value=' + country.id + ']').data('code')` perhaps.